# Build a string to pass as $set parameter

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to update a document in a collection through the use of update, and $set.

I'm trying to set the 'purchased' boolean to true/false, depending on user input.

if I do
`{$set : {'lists.$.items.<items position>.purchased' : bought}}`, assuming that bought is a boolean, it updates perfectly.  However, if I try to do

```
var updateString = 'lists.$.items.' + itemPosition + '.purchased';
{$set : { updateString : bought}};
```

it always updates 0 documents.  I have tried multiple variations, such as `var updateString = '"lists.$.items.' + itemPosition + '.purchased"';`

If i `console.log(updateString)`, and paste the output into the $set it works perfectly.

I need to be able to build these update parameters dynamically, and I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not being very smart about this, as it turns out.

It was more me trying to use updateString as a key that was failing.

The way I got around this was to do:

```
var updateString = 'lists.$.items.' + itemPosition + '.purchased';
var query = {'$set' : {}};
query['$set'][updateString] = purchased;
```

And then simply pass in query as the second parameter to the Mongoose update call.